# Is there a built-in or widely-available uncased string type for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

I often find myself dealing with strings for which comparison to other strings should ignore case, ie Oracle parameters. I see too much `ToUpper()` or `ToUpperInvariant()`. I thought about building a little class that contains a reference to a `string` whose getters and setters take care of this for me, but I was wondering if this sort of class is built into .NET or some widely-used library. Ideally, such a class would have these advantages:

1. There would be no need to transform `ToUpper()` (read the next to see why it isn't just implementing a special comparator)
2. It would use less memory (because there would be no need to store `char`s that have the same value as distinct values) - ie for some subset of `char` there would be a map taking each index to its oppositely cased index, saving some number of bits per `char` depending on the language

Edit 0: I get point #1, and I understand why it is better to use  the `StringComparison` argument, but is it not reasonable to code a separate `Type` of `string` that uses this `StringComparison` by default? Otherwise I am typing that everywhere I see a field of that sort (`username`, `emailAddress`, `vendorCode`, etc)

Edit 1: What about point #2 ? Would it be such a waste of time to shorten all of your `char` indices by at least 26 in a string-intensive application? Maybe that's not worded correctly...

Edit 2 (corrected math): For example, on #1, say I have a `Username`-like field which is always *persisted* in some legacy DB as upper via a stored procedure, and this logic is too pervasive to change throughout all DB procedures.

The usual length of `char` is 2^16 I think, but suppose I know that the DB treats it as if it has 2^8 at most. So not only do I have to keep explicitly writing the `StringComparison` over and over again, but the application is wasting 8 bits per `char`. If I am forced to store about 100000 strings in memory for some operation, that means I am forced to use 10^5*8/(10^6 * 8) = 0.5 MB, which is not very much at all.

Comment: If you're seeing lots of `ToUpper`, you're not looking at decent code. Bearing in mind the turkish I problem, what you should be seeing are calls to comparison functions, etc, that have an `IgnoreCase` option being passed to them.

Comment: Did you try searching for [.net string compare case insensitive](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+string+compare+case+insensitive&oq=.Net+String+compa&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.98704j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @crashmstr see request #2

Comment: @crashmstr and edited #1 . I'm kind of playing the devil's advocate here, but I'm also a little intrigued about the reasoning why this does not presently exist.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: Regarding your first edit, consider moving the comparison work to a static utility method or extension method that does this standard comparison for you. (It will help avoid violations of DRY too) EDIT: And regarding your other edits, I'm wondering if this is a case of premature optimization. Working with strings in the CLR is pretty decent (as long as you don't _abuse_ them).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever @Chris_Sinclair even if I move the comparison to a utility method, and assuming my concerns about `char` length are stupid, the fact remains that the utility method needs to be called for every instance of comparison of those "uncased" strings. So instead of saying "I have an uncased string", I am forcing myself to be careful in very case that I have an uncased string to use that method, right? My thinking is that instead of saying `CrappyString MyString` one time, I have to remember that `MyString` is uncased every time I want to do a comparison

Comment: Based on your most recent edits (Edit 2 is current) you seem to be aiming more for a shift from using UTF-16 to using UTF-8. But your size comparisons seem to be a bit confused. You don't save `2^8` bit per char. You save `8` bits, or one byte.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: Yes. If you like, you could _also_ roll a wrapping class for `String` which stores the string value as a private field and implements its own `Equals` override/overloads and comparison logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, that changes the math dramatically. So my real question was, I guess, why hasn't this been generally adopted into .NET and Java? And from your answer I am assuming that `char`'s length is dependent on encoding and that the savings from wrapping `string` are not worth the pain and lack of portability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of calling `ToUpper` or `ToUpperInvariant` for string comparison ignoring case you can use the `string.Equals` overload [`String.Equals Method (String, String, StringComparison`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes `StringComparison` parameter to specify ignore case.

```
if (string.Equals("ABC", "abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))//true
{

}
```

or

```
if ("ABC".Equals("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
}
```

Comment: If your unicode is normalized (and it probably is) `StringComparison.OridnalIgnoreCase` is faster.

Comment: @MattWilko, [`string.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9h2fbth(v=vs.110).aspx) overload supports for ignore case. [`string.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) has an overload for in-sensitive case comparison, which can be used instead of `Contains`

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. There is exctly one string type in .NET - System.String.

String.Equals may have an IgnoreCase option.